# wrap result of method to an intermediate object which deferred execution of original method

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, design-patterns, typescript-decorator

pseudocode:

```
class Transaction {
    withTransaction(trx);
    exec()
}

class Test {
    @somedecorator 
    getUserById(id) {
        return this.trx(this.tableName).where({ id });
    }
}

const inst = new Test()
const res = inst.getUserById(1);
res.withTransaction(myTrx);// call `this.trx(this.tableName).where({ id });` with `myTrx`  
res.exec()// return result of `this.trx(this.tableName).where({ id });` with default trx
```

Example in plane JS what behavior I want to get

```
class BaseRepo {
    constructor(tableName, trx) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.trx = trx
    }

}
function getUserByIdFn(id) {
    return this.trx() + `(id number => ${id})`;
}

function decorateMethod(fn, self){
    return (...args) => {
        return {
            withTransaction(trx) {
                return fn.call({
                    ...self,
                    trx,
                },...args)
            },
            then(resolve) {
                return resolve(fn.call(self, ...args));
            }
        }
    }
}
class UserRepo extends BaseRepo {
    constructor(trx) {
        super('user', trx)
    }
    getUserById = decorateMethod(getUserByIdFn, this);
}
// trx here is function for simplicity 
const user = new UserRepo(() => 'original function  result');
(async function main() {
    const result1 = await user.getUserById(1);
    console.log(result1); // original function  result(id number => 1)
    const result2 = user.getUserById(3);
    const t = result2.withTransaction(() => 'another call'); 
    console.log(t); // another call(id number => 3)
})()
```

I need some approach to wrap `getUserById` result to in `Transaction` object which deferred execution of original method. I know how todo that with plane Js, but how do it in Typescript with all typing. Is it possible to do somehow? Some best practice?

Comment: The body of your `class Transaction` appears to be a syntax error.

Comment: "*I know how todo that with plane Js*" - please show us that code, and your attempt at adding types to it, so that we can help you with that specific problem.

Comment: I know it's pseudocode or it's better to add JavaScript example to clarify my thought? But the solution in plane Js it's use bind, typescript doesn't work good with bind

Comment: @Bergi I have added example, I hope it's clear now

Comment: I don't think your plain js solution even work properly. With `fn.call({...self, trx}, …)`, you're not able to call other methods of your instance in the `getUserById` body.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by return wrapped object clearly. But I wanted to do it like `async` function works

```
async test() {
   return 1
}
const data = test()
```

data is `Promise` wrapped around 1 value, it's what exactly  I wanted.
But instead `Promise` my own `Object`

My solution:

```
import { Knex } from 'knex';
import { UserDatabaseType } from '../../database-types/common';

export interface RepoFunctionType<FUNCTION_RETURN> {
  (trx: Knex.Transaction | Knex): FUNCTION_RETURN;
}

class TrxPromise<FUNCTION_RETURN> {
  private execute: RepoFunctionType<FUNCTION_RETURN>;
  private defaultTrx: Knex;

  constructor(defaultTrx: Knex, execute: RepoFunctionType<FUNCTION_RETURN>) {
    this.execute = execute;
    this.defaultTrx = defaultTrx;
  }

  async then(resolve: (arg0: FUNCTION_RETURN) => void) {
    const result = await this.execute(this.defaultTrx);
    resolve(result);
  }

  async withTransaction(trx: Knex.Transaction) {
    const result = await this.execute(trx);
    return result;
  }
  originalPromise() {
    return this.execute(this.defaultTrx);
  }
}

type ElementType<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<
  infer ElementType
>
  ? ElementType
  : never;

class UserRepo<DATABASE_TYPE> {
  private trx: Knex;
  private tableName: string;

  constructor(trx: Knex, tableName: string) {
    this.trx = trx;
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

  create<K extends (keyof DATABASE_TYPE & string)[]>({
    data,
    returning,
  }: {
    data: Partial<DATABASE_TYPE>[];
    returning?: K;
  }) {
    return new TrxPromise(
      this.trx,
      async (trx): Promise<Array<Pick<DATABASE_TYPE, ElementType<K>>>> => {
        if (!returning) {
          return (await (trx(this.tableName)
            .insert(data)
            .returning('*') as unknown)) as Promise<
            Array<Pick<DATABASE_TYPE, ElementType<K>>>
          >;
        }

        return (trx(this.tableName)
          .insert(data)
          .returning(returning) as unknown) as Promise<
          Promise<Array<Pick<DATABASE_TYPE, ElementType<K>>>>
        >;
      },
    );
  }
}

const r = new UserRepo<UserDatabaseType>({}, 'test');
(async function main() {
  const data = r.create({
    data: [{ firstName: 'test', lastName: 'test', address: 'test' }],
    returning: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
  });
  const a = await data.withTransaction({});
  const c = await data.originalPromise();
  const finalResult = await data;
  finalResult.map(t => t.firstName)
})();
```